# Comparar dia e mês de uma data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, data

No *MySQL* tenho salvo a data de nascimento de uma pessoa, preciso montar uma `query` que me retorne os aniversariantes da semana, aqueles que fazem aniversário de hoje até hoje + 7 dias.

Estou tentando assim:

```
//Metodo da tela de listagem
public function birthdayDeed()
{
    // construtor de query
    $criteria = CriteriaBuilder::create()
    // seleciono a tabela
        ->tables('clients')
    // adiciono uma condição da data ser maior ou igual a de hoje
        ->_and('birth', '>=', date('Y-m-d', time()))
    // E se data for menor ou igual daqui a 7 dias
        ->_and('birth', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"))); 


    $this
        ->title( Language::get('client', 't-birthday') )
        ->view('client', 'list')
        ->attr('clients', $this->toArray( (new Client())->debug()->listAll(null, $criteria) ))
        ->display();
}
```

Que resulta na query:

```
'SELECT * FROM  clients   WHERE birth >=  :birth  AND birth <= :birth1;'
```

Sei onde está ocorrendo o erro, estou comparando também o ano, logo ficaria por exemplo:

```
birth: 1996-10-30
condição: 1996-10-30 >= 2016-10-28 AND 1996-10-30 <= 2016-11-04
```

Logo nunca entraria nessa condição, preciso saber como comparar somente o dia e mês, alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: No mysql use a função `day()` e `month()` para comparar pedaços especificos de uma data.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber esse `CriteriaBuilder` é um pacote, ou é de algum framework, se puder dizer! obrigado.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é de um microframework que fiz para fazer meus projetos, tenho no GitHub, mas está incompleto, faltando alguns commits com correções de bug: https://github.com/legionlab/troubadour

Comment: @Ivcs muito legal vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com as respostas, deu pra entender mais e pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o assunto, achei uma solução juntando uma série de perguntas parecidas:

```
SELECT * FROM clientsWHERE 
     DATE_FORMAT(birth,'%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') AND
     DATE_FORMAT(birth,'%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY,'%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 3):

Faça a comparação extraindo os pedaços certos (dia e mês) da data, no mysql pode usar as funções `day()` e `month()`.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
->_and('day(birth)', '>=', date('d'))
->_and('day(birth)', '<=', date('d', strtotime("+7 days"))
->_and('month(birth)', '=', date('m')
```

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente, mas é só eu alterar um pouco o conceito da lógica, pois no fim do mês, como hoje, ficaria: se `dia >= 28 AND dia <= 04`, mas é só realizar alguns ajustes. Obrigado aí!!

Comment: @lvcs verdade, vou corrigir logo altero a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM table
WHERE birth between date_add(updated_at, interval year(now())-year(updated_at) year) and
                    date_add( date_add(updated_at, interval year(now())-year(updated_at) year) , interval 7 day)
```